# Catching a train in Montparnasse from Charles de Gaulle airport

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, short-connections, cdg

I need to travel from Charles de Gaulle airport to Montparnasse to catch a TGV (Train à Grande Vitesse or "high-speed train"). What is the best and fastest method to do that? Train?

I only have an hour and 30 minutes between arrival at CDG and the pre-booked TGV departure from Montparnasse (I didn't do the booking myself). I am concerned that may not be enough time.

Comment: Not not actually an answer to your question, but you may want to have a look at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26146/how-do-i-get-from-charles-de-gaulle-airport-cdg-to-gare-montparnasse

Answer (score 5):

An hour and a half is not even within the realm of possible. Where is your TGV going? You might want to look into changing the train ticket to a train leaving from CDG. Trains that leave Montparnasse usually have [an alternative line from CDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9roport_Charles_de_Gaulle_2_TGV). If you're going towards Tours/Bordeaux or Le Mans/Rennes you should be able to take the train right in CDG.

Comment: Thank you. The train ticket to Nantes was booked by someone else. I'll have to try to get them to change the ticket. Many thanks for your advice. You've confirmed what I feared.

Comment: It appears that there are in fact direct trains from CDG to Nantes.