# CDG to Bordeaux train options

Tags: cdg

I need to get from Paris CDG to Bordeaux and there appears to be a direct train from the airport, but it seems to be full. Is going to Montparnasse a viable option to catch another train?

Comment: Yes but also look for other options where you do not travel into Paris to leave it again.

Comment: Notice that there's currently a strike going at the SNCF. As many trains are canceled, that might explain the lack of available seats on the CDG-Bordeaux line (and a general lack of available seats on all lines). Depending on your schedule, things might get better at a future date.

Comment: The strike is on a 2-days of strike, 3-days normal cycle. All trains during the 2 days of strike are shown as full even if they aren't, as they don't know yet if they will be running. If at all possible, try to avoid the strike days.

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

Yes

### Longer answer

You can either take the direct train which is a little slower (given it goes around Paris at slower speeds) or go to Montparnasse where the high-speed services run from. You will have a lot more services from there but you have to deal with the hassle of going to Montparnasse. There is a [direct bus service](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26146/how-do-i-get-from-charles-de-gaulle-airport-cdg-to-gare-montparnasse?rq=1) from CDG to Montparnasse as well as local rail (RER+transfer on the Metro). It'll take 1 hour at least to go from CDG to Montparnasse. I would be tempted to either (a) try to grab a train from CDG (more convenient) or fly from CDG to BOD. It could even be cheaper.

[image]

Comment: Second the recommendation to fly. One advantage of flying to BOD is that you avoid using the public transportation in Paris, which isn't the cleanest and safest, especially in the northern suburbs. Even passing through CDG is enough of a chore anyway.